# if $C_1, C_2, C_3$,... are sets such that $C_k \supset C_{k+1}$...

Tags: elementary-set-theory

if $C_1, C_2, C_3$,... are sets such that $C_k \supset C_{k+1}$, k = 1, 2, 3, ..., $\lim_{k\to\infty}$ is defined as the intersection $C_1\cap C_2 \cap C_3 \cap ...$. Find $\lim_{k\to\infty} C_k$ if

$C_k = \{x:2 \lt x \leq 2 + 1/k\}$

Well I did this:

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}2 + \frac{1}{k} = 2$$

Which leaves the set

$c_{\infty} = \{x: 2 \lt x \leq 2\} = \emptyset$

I believe because x cannot be both greater than 2 and equal to 2.

Would this be correct?

Comment: Yes sounds true for me... You can say this another way. For each $\epsilon>0$ we have $$2+\epsilon\notin C_k$$ where $k>\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}$

Comment: I see. Thanks @MostafaAyaz .

Comment: @UdayKhanna I think it would imply that. I think I'm missing your point though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct. If you want to explicitly use your observation it's just enough to say that if by contradition $\exists x \in \bigcap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} C_k$ then
$$
  2 < x \leq 2 + \frac{1}{k} \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}
$$
By definition of limit then there exists a $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
  k > k_0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad
  2 + \frac{1}{k} \leq 2 + \frac{x - 2}{2}
$$
Where the key oservation is that $\displaystyle \frac{x - 2}{2} > 0$. If it was a non negative this argument would have failed. Hence
$$
  2 < x < 2 + \frac{x - 2}{2} \quad \Rightarrow \quad 0 < x-2 < \frac{x-2}{2}
$$
That is our contradiction.

Comment: I really don't get you @JayTuma, but I will accept it to close the answer out. Thanks.